# Reloading the page on FF not changing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having this issue that I can't figure out what is happening:
I'm using Angular and it's routing mechanism.

so I have a url:

```
<a href="#/videos/detail/{{video.Id}}" onclick="location.reload();">
    <div class="card-image">
        <img ng-src="{{video.ThumbnailUrl?video.ThumbnailUrl:'img/images.png'}}" src="" />
    </div>
</a>
```

As you can see there is an `onclick="location.reload();` this works on Chrome and IE9. But on FF it's doing the following:

1. Click on link
2. The url get's updated
3. The location.reload() get's called an the page is being refreshed
4. The url and angular view, go's back to the page where the link is clicked
5. When pressing 'F5' the actual page and url are being loaded in

I also tried doing `location.reload(true);` for if maybe the route was cached or so, but no luck.

In case you are wondering why the refresh and location:
I need to refresh the page for a plugin to reload (due to a bug in it) and this method was the first I could think of.

**EDIT:**
Eventually done by doing a combination of Angular and some Jquery;

So the final html looked like this;

```
<a href="#" class="prevent" ng-click="redirectwithreload('# />videos/detail/'+video.Id)" >
    <div class="card-image">
        <img ng-src="{{video.ThumbnailUrl?video.ThumbnailUrl:'img/images.png'}}" src="" />
    </div>
</a>
```

The directive looked like this

```
.directive('videoCard', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/video-card.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $location) {
            $scope.redirectWithReload = function (url) {
                var toUrl = location.href.split('#')[0] + url;
                location.replace(toUrl);
            }
        },
        compile: function () {
            return {
                post: function () {
                    $('a.prevent').click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
})
```

the class `prevent` was just for my Jquery to prevent default
and went for a ng-click, because of if I ever need to add more vars to the url, it's now very easy to do :)

Thanks for all the help! especially: @mplungjan

Comment: What is it supposed to do? the # is an anchor. The script on the page should react to this. I cannot see what the location.reload is used for. try removing it

Comment: @mplungjan: redirecting and then refreshing

Comment: Please read my amended comment

Comment: this is an XY problem. Solve the reason you need to reload the plugin instead.

Comment: @mplungjan I've already spend 2 weeks on trying to fix the plugin, 1 month on top of that on the issue why I need that plugin. So this is already a fix for a fix for a fix :p

Comment: Alternative `<a href="#" onclick="location.replace(location.href.split('#')[0]+'#/videos/detail/{{video.Id}}'); return false">`

Comment: @mplungjan Just for completeness' sake, and for getting a hang of best practice: [stop misusing return false;](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

Comment: @BramVanroy no I won't stop on an inline non-jquery onclick in a comment. If it works, I can elaborate and use unobtrusive and e.preventDefault()

Comment: @mplungjan angular is not liking that sollution (throwing an error), also it doesn't render the ID

Comment: Searching for the mistake, but not seeing it, copied for your answer :)

Comment: Did you add the missing quote? can we store the ID in an attribute?
`<a href="#" onclick="location.replace(location.href.split('#')[0]+'#/videos/detail/'+this.id); return false" id="{{video.I‌​d}}">`?

Comment: Yep I saw that eventually, but the last way with the this.id works! and actually like it more then my original solution makes more sense. Can you post this as reply? then I can mark it as solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store the ID in an attribute and use replace, you can do

```
<a href="#" id="{{video.I‌​d}}"
onclick="location.replace(location.href.split('#')[0]+'#/videos/detail/'+this.id‌​); return false">
```

or for the purist (here jQuery, I do not do Angular):

```
<a href="#" class="vids" id="{{video.I‌​d}}">
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $(".vids").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.replace(location.href.split('#')[0]+'#/videos/detail/'+this.id‌​); "
  });
});
```

For more parameters:

```
<a href="#" class="vids" data-id="{{video.I‌​d}}" data-target="somewhere">
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $(".vids").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.replace(location.href.split('#')[0]+'#/videos/detail/'+
      $(this).data("id‌"​)+'/'+
      $(this).data("target"​));
  });
});
```

Comment: Any quick suggestions on how to add multiple variables?

Comment: I just noticed that the page isn't being refreshed with the location.replace(). is tihs normal behaviour? (I'm using the $(this).data() thingy

Comment: Hmm, if not, then tack on a new Date().getTime() as suggested on a downvoted post, but make sure it has the right leading character (& or / depending on how you parse your URLS)

Answer (score 0):

To force to render the page, you can use :

```
$route.reload();
```

cf. [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) :

> Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed.
>
> As a result of that, ngView creates new scope, reinstantiates the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can add method in controller with wanted functionality:

```
// view
<a ng-click="redirectWithReload('#/videos/detail/'+video.Id)">

// controller
$scope.redirectWithReload = function(url) {
   $location.url(url); // use $location service
}
```

Comment: This could work, but this is in an directive, so I'm looking for adding it to the directive code.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try any of these in the onclick:

1. history.go(0);
2. window.location.href = window.location.href;

Please try:

```
window.location.href = "your_page.html" + "?" + Date.parse(new Date());
```

This method makes sure not to use any cached page and I apply this whenever a page needs to be reloaded through JS

Comment: They do exact the same thing, so doesn't matter here